# Angular stop function from self-invoking

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement new functionality to my pet-project.

Basically I have this function:

```
public makePayment() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/';
    return this.http.post(url + 'paypal/make/payment?sum=8', {}).subscribe(res => console.log(JSON.stringify(res)));
  }
```

And I wan't it to be invoked here:

```
<a [routerLink]="makePayment()">MAKE A DEPOSIT</a>
```

However It's being invoked on the load of the page and starts to spam my backend with requests.

I've done something similar a couple of times and it worked fine. Could you help me with understanding the problem?

Comment: don't you want tu use (click) instead of [routerLink]? angular is making all those requests because it keeps evaluating the result of the function so that it can set routerLink property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routerlinks are meant to navigate, not to call a function. Try this instead:

`<div (click)="makePayment()">MAKE A DEPOSIT</div>`

This won't be styled like a link, you'll have to add css for that.